# Best practices and examples on how to organize object oriented javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, namespaces, module

I am a newbie to JavaScript and programming in general. I've started creating my first web app and I would like to rewrite it using an object oriented approach. I've read some articles and book chapters on object oriented JS about how to simulate namespaces, the module pattern and so, but I am having a hard time thinking about how to organize my code inside objects, hope you can help me with this or point me in the right direction to some examples or best practices.

I was thinking to organize it sort of like jQuery with a namespace (called app maybe) and all my app functions inside it, for example app.func1, app.func2, however I have other functions which are used inside those which are like utilities and I would like them to have another name, maybe something like app.util.func... Also my code creates custom objects inside my app, but I don't know where is the right place to put them and their constructors inside my namespace.

Any suggestions, ideas, best practices, templates, or examples on how to organize object oriented javascript? Examples on creating simple library like code would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I've read some articles and book chapters on object oriented JS about how to simulate namespaces, ...

I wouldn't simulate classical OO paradigms in JavaScript. You should stick with what's natural for JavaScript.

Don't do classical inheritance. Use prototypal inheritance or no inheritance at all: Composition/decoration look a lot nicer than inheritance in JavaScript.

You don't need namespaces. They cause unnecessary indirection and cause enterprisey code clutter. Use a good module pattern that hides your functions and variables inside closures.

Try a module loader like RequireJS. You can hide your modules in their own files and closures and let RequireJS do dependency injection magic for you.

Organizing JS application files is a very broad topic. You could organize your classes based on separation of concerns by using paradigms like MVC or MVP. In terms of project organization, building your application on Maven (and following its conventions) could be an option.

Since your question has been at a very high level, I just wanted to throw in some ideas and keywords that you may want to Google and read up on. Maybe after some research and trials and tribulations, you can come back and ask about more specific problems.

Comment: I would argue that namespaces are important.  You don't want to clutter up the global `window` object with a ton of different functions and variables.

Comment: I didn't say they weren't important. They are usually over-used. There are far better ways to keep the global scope uncluttered. I'm simply against uses like: `com.mycompany.mylib.enterprise.ajax`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm googling more on those ideas.

Comment: After preaching the opposite about a year ago, I thought I should now mention that I've actually started using "classical" inheritance via John Resig's simple inheritance and found it to be quite convenient in a project with a lot of widget classes. But, I think it still depends on the context.